# Create a custom text shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text

I have some plain text and I was curious as to how to create a custom text shadow behind it. I have another set of text I would like to use as the shadow but I'm not sure what to do as in angling it and what not.

I can use either illustrator or photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial I found should explain things pretty well... it's not that hard. Since it's only part of the tutorial, I've linked you to the start of the shadow making. You might have to wait a few seconds. This one is for illustrator.

https://youtu.be/HB7CpyENtHY?t=4m2s

(From video instructions on request in case video gets deleted, is not accessible, or something prohibits viewing in the future: duplicate text, reflect text. Change the reflected text to a black to transparent black gradient that fades out away from the main text. Next, go to Transform --> Shear and choose your angle using horizontal axis. Lastly, align your shadow to your main text.)

Comment: You should include the relevant content from the video inside of the answer itself so that it will be valid if the video is ever removed or YouTube is down

Comment: I don't think that would happen because YT isn't likely to go away and the video has remained up for three years and has no background music, but I added it anyway. :) I guess it's also a good resource to add in case younger designers have YT blocked by parental controls though. Thanks for the suggestion. ... Did you downvote though? If so, why?

Comment: Youtube might be down for people due to other reasons such as the goverment being pissed at google this month (china, for example). Employer blocks youtube (your supposed to work not watch vids on youtube). But also because skim reading is faster than watching a video. But most importantly: You do not subconciously pick up other peoples bad habits with reflex cells. As to why you got down voted i don't know but can guess just as well as you.